# how to show more than 1 row in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

```
  $(this).closest('tr').next().show();
```

right now im using this code. But i want to show more than 1 hidden row. the hidden rows are results from select query using a row on top. So sometime there are more than 1 row or no row at all

maybe by using a for loop? but how do i count the next closest rows with the same id

```
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;">click</td>
 <asp:ource ID="SqlC" runat="server"
                                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:string %>"
 SelectCommand="SELECT* FROM table WHERE  RegNo=click""
```

after all these

```
<tr class:"show" style: display:none>
<td> show</td>
```

Comment: Do you want to show the rows one by one, or altogether?

Comment: The closest group of rows altogether

Comment: Could you post the html code for clarification please?

Comment: when i click  a row.. the search query runs and all the resulting rows comes below the clicked row

Comment: You could use a for loop like so: 

for(x =0; x<$('#rowid tr').length; x++){}